# Отображение Интернета

Tags: графы, визуализация

У меня есть несколько тысяч ip-адресов и различная информация об устройствах, которым они принадлежат. А теперь мне надо отобразить эти несколько тысяч узлов. Отобразить на графе. Было бы здорово, если бы я знал как они физически связаны друг с другом. Рёбра графа изображали бы кабель. Но... чего нет, того нет.

Как логически связать сетевые устройства для визуализации?

Answer (score 1):

Так вот сразу сложно сказать, но на самом деле эту информацию можно попытаться выявить. Для этого предлагаю просто делать mtr (он же traceroute) на каждый ip и следить за "трассой" - списком хостов, по которых проходит "сигнал". Эти хосты с большой вероятностью будут связаны напрямую.

Конечно, к некоторым хостам можно дойти разными способами, но это в интернете всегда так (Иначе один кабель перебили и все, умерло все).

Возможно, придется делать трейс с многих машин.

В интернете все постоянно меняется, поэтому через месяц другой ситуация может сильно поменяться.

Comment: Согласен, traceroute - хороший вариант, но он даёт довольно субъективное представление. Я получу маршруты от своих ip-адресов до целевых. Возможно, в трассы попадут и адреса, которые находятся в моей БД. Но я в этом сомневаюсь.

Comment: Вполне может быть следующая ситуация. Пусть есть два хоста, x и y, и путь к ним такой a - b - c - x и a - b - d - y (где а - компьютер, с которого сканируют). Значит, как минимум существует путь x - c - d - y.

Также, можно посмотреть на список айпи и попробовать найти среди них каких-нибудь хостеров или что то подобное. И взять там на неделю-другую хостинг (ну не прям сразу на нужных ip, но, к примеру, в той же подсети).

Answer (score 0):

Провести аудит сети, построить граф маршрутов, а также получить данные об открытых портах, сетевых службах и во многих случаях - об операционных системах на машинах в сети, позволяет open-sources проект [Zenmap](https://nmap.org/zenmap/), являющийся, по сути, GUI для nmap. Работает как на Linux, так и на Windows.

В Zenmap после сканирования сети топологию (граф) вы можете увидеть на вкладке Topology, соответственно. Попробуйте.

Также есть интересное open-sources решение [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org/) от Антона Кекса, я его пока что не пробовал, но слышал хорошие отзывы. Написано на Java, работает под всеми распространёнными ОС.